# AWK - splitting a multiple header file into separate files?

Tags: awk

I have a file that is unusually structured and I am trying to split it into multiple files based on the first column ($1) being populated. Essentially it is a header for each 'section' of the file.

The column doesn't have any pattern either so hence random_text_1 and random_text_2 as a column name so I can't use pattern matching...

Sample file...

```
random_text_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5
,1,a,"1, a",abc
,2,,"2",abc
,3,c,"3,c",def
random_text2,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5
,1,x,"2, x",abcdef
,2,,"2",abcdef
,3,y,"3,y",defefg
```

I am tying to split the file into 'blocks', i.e.,

One file would be...

```
random_text_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5
,1,a,"1, a",abc
,2,,"2",abc
,3,c,"3,c",def
```

And the other...

```
random_text2,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5
,1,x,"2, x",abcdef
,2,,"2",abcdef
,3,y,"3,y",defefg
```

If I do something like this it splits the file but only gives me the contents with the 'headers' removed and if I do $1!="" it just gives me the header in separate files...

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = ","; FPAT = "([^" OFS "]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} $1=="" { print $0 > "output-file" $1 } ' test-file.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '$1!=""{close(out); out="out"++c} {print > out}' file
```

You don't need the `close(out)` if you're using gawk as it handles closing files when necessary for you.

Make the output file name assignment `out="output-file" $1` to name the output files based on the header lines `$1` as in your posted script if you like, I can't tell from your input if that would create unique files or not while I know the above will do so.

Comment: That is great! Thanks.